# getting error 500 with .htaccess when pointing a php file (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i made a simple .htaccess file to expose the problem.

I want that all request made to the folder redirect to a subfolder file "app/index.php"

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) app/index.php [QSA]
```

And this works fine on with the basic url of my hoster (like `http//myname.hosting.com/htaccessFolder`

The problem is that i have a domain pointing on this folder, and when accessed to it, server return `Internal Server Error 500`.

If i do this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) somefile.php [QSA]
```

Redirection works only when file does not exists (404 not found error occured). when the file exists i get a 500 error too.

I've asked the hosting support without success for the moment..

EDIT :

Strangely, when i write :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) somefile.txt [QSA]
```

it works on bot, so it seems that the problem comes from executing php files..

EDIT2 :

Here is the real .htaccess file i try to use :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    #RewriteRule .? - [L]

    #####################

    RewriteRule (.*) app/public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule app/public/(.*) $1



    #####################

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} question2answers/(.+)
    #RewriteRule .? - [L]

    #####################

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

You can see that only the public block is not commented but when i go to the website i get this :
The requested URL /cgi-bin/php5.fcgi/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/in.....

but i request a file in the public folder (like http://website.com/css/style.css (which is in public/css) it works as expected.
When i'm not commenting the last block, i get a 500 error.

Comment: i've asked the support for it, don't know where i can get it

Comment: Usually it's somwhere near your www root directory. Look for `log` or `logs` folder.

Comment: i have a mutualised host, so i can't go upper than public_html folder..

Comment: error.log is required. We can't guess what is the error. Maybe an error is a simple mistype.

Comment: I asked them again 2hours ago but they do not respond.. I'm trying since i've asked the question to find what's going on but just finding some strange things.. For example, it works if i add some `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before. (When file does not exist) and php file shows

Comment: Whн don't you just leave `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before?

Comment: I need to redirect to another folder, the current folder must be invisible for the user

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a solution to avoid redirections :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #####################

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} stop
    RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

    #####################

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} question2answers/(.*)
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?htaccess=stop [L,QSA]

    #####################

    RewriteRule (.*) app/public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?htaccess=stop [L]

    RewriteRule app/public/(.*) $1


    #####################


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?htaccess=stop [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

I do not understand all but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your htaccess file:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

It turns off content negotiation which can sometimes screw with how URLs map to files with extensions like php.